# ISPF reconnect successful but does not show ISPF primary options menu

Tags: mainframe, ispf, tso

I have a problem reconnecting to ISPF. After the TSO/E LOGON screen, the screen on the attached picture shows and says that logon reconnection is successful, but it doesn't proceed to ISPF. If I type any commands, ISPF, logoff, etc. it locks. [image]

Comment: You should see three asterisks below the IKT00300I message, do you? You need to hit `ENTER` when that message appears (this is what the asterisks are telling you). *And*, you will be back where you were at disconnect time, so don't necessarily expect the ISPF POM.

Comment: The problem is that the asterisks do not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are connecting with the same terminal settings(mod5, mod2, etc).
Sometime you need to use PA2 to force a rebuild of the current panel.  If you disconnected while running a CLIST/EXEC/program,  then you might need to ATTN out of it.

Answer (score 0):

It could have been that you were in a process that was looping or hung, and you were simply reconnected to that looping/hanging process.  Next time, try the ATTN key.  I have seen some installations set up the logon screen/process where if you do not choose RECONNECT, your still-active prior session will be terminated prior to logging you on.  This is a nice setup, especially for hang situations like you were probably in.